# Eclipse multiple contexts plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-plugin

I have a question on multiple contexts in eclipse plugin, Can I have a handler definition in plugin with  multiple contexts in  tag? like here:

```
<enabledWhen>
         <with variable="activeContexts">
            <and>
                  <iterate operator="or">
                          <equals
                              value="context1"/>
                  </iterate>
                  <iterate operator="or">
                        <equals
                            value="context2"/>
                    </iterate>
            </and>
         </with>         
</enabledWhen>
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

You can. And as far as I can see, your expression should work as is.